# How to combine series and pandas' dataframe into one dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series `A:[1, 2, 3]`

and I have a dataframe df:

```
                  Open   
Date                                                                         
2000-01-04 8644.910156     
2000-01-05 8690.599609    
2000-01-06 8900.559570
```

How to attach A into dataframe df like:

```
                    Open    A
Date                                                                         
2000-01-04   8644.910156    1  
2000-01-05   8690.599609    2  
2000-01-06   8900.559570    3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC then

`df['A'] = A.values` should work

as this avoids the problem of index alignment as `.values` returns an anonymous np array

```
In [438]:
import io
import pandas
t="""Date,Open
2000-01-04,8644.910156
2000-01-05,8690.599609
2000-01-06,8900.559570"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), index_col=[0])
df

Out[438]:
                   Open
Date                   
2000-01-04  8644.910156
2000-01-05  8690.599609
2000-01-06  8900.559570

In [441]:    
A = pd.Series(np.arange(1,4))
A

Out[441]:
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: int32

In [442]:
df['A'] = A.values
df

Out[442]:
                   Open  A
Date                      
2000-01-04  8644.910156  1
2000-01-05  8690.599609  2
2000-01-06  8900.559570  3
```